# jQuery PHP Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got a problem maybe is simple but dont know how to load jquery_post.php when I send the data for jquery_send.php I resume I send information from jquery_send.php to jquery_post.php and I want that after send the page jquery_post.php load with the data

This is what I have in jquery_send.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
var vname = $("#name").val();
var vemail = $("#email").val();
if(vname=='' && vemail=='')
{
alert("Please fill out the form");
}
else if(vname=='' && vemail!==''){alert('Name field is required')}
else if(vemail=='' && vname!==''){alert('Email field is required')}
else{
$.post("jquery_post.php",
{ 
name:vname,
email:vemail
},
function(response,status){ 
alert("*----Received Data----*nnResponse : " + response+"nnStatus : " + status);
$("#form")[0].reset();
});
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<h2>jQuery Ajax $.post() Method</h2>
<hr>
<form id="form" method="post">
<div id="namediv"><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/><br></div>
<div id="emaildiv"><label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/></div>
</form>
<button id="btn">Send Data</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in jquery_post.php I have this:

```
<?php
if($_POST["name"])
{
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
echo "Welcome ". $name ."!";
?>
```

Comment: What data are you getting in response? By the way, I think you should check your post URL. Try `http://yourhost/jquery_post.php` instead of just `jquery_post.php`.

Comment: You're missing the closing bracket in jquery_post.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try, this may help

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
var vname = $("#name").val();
var vemail = $("#email").val();
if(vname=='' && vemail=='')
{
alert("Please fill out the form");
}
else if(vname=='' && vemail!==''){alert('Name field is required')}
else if(vemail=='' && vname!==''){alert('Email field is required')}
else{
$.post("post.php",
{ 
name:vname,
email:vemail
},
function(response,status){ 
alert("*----Received Data----*nnResponse : " + response+"nnStatus : " + status);
$("#form")[0].reset();
window.location.href = 'post.php';
});
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<div id="main">
<h2>jQuery Ajax $.post() Method</h2>
<hr>
<form id="form" method="post">
<div id="namediv"><label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name"/><br></div>
<div id="emaildiv"><label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/></div>
</form>
<button id="btn">Send Data</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in jquery_post.php I have made some changes When you post data to jquery_post.php it will create a session named "user" you can retrieve name any time from the session as I did.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST["name"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
}
echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['user'] ."!";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine, but you have a syntax error in you `jquery_post.php`

```
<?php
if($_POST["name"])
{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    echo "Welcome ". $name ."!";
}   // you missed this
?>
```

it was returning `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file`

Comment: I did that but what can i do to load jquery_post.php with the data after i click in send data

Comment: Save data in db or session and use `window.location` in your js code to redirect